# Access object from js file inside Laravel blade?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to use the package [Sortablejs](https://github.com/SortableJS/sortablejs) within my blade file.

Thus, I installed it with npm and created a `sortable.js` file inside my assets with this content

```
import Sortable from "sortablejs";
```

which is compiled into the public folder using webpack.mix.js

I expected that I could use it like this within my blade:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/sortable.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var documentlists = $('#documentlist');
    Sortable.create(documentlists);
</script>
```

However, this results in the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Sortable is not defined
>  http://localhost:8004/admin/settings/businessagreement:715

Why can't I include it like this and how would I need to do it?

Comment: make ```npm run watch``` then try

Comment: @AhmedShams I did compile with npm

Comment: Add `window.Sortable = Sortable` in your sotrable.js file to expose it to the window global or (even better) move the `Sortable.create($('#documentlist'))` in your sortable.js file

Answer (score 0):

Your `import` statement needs to be in the same file as your `Sortable` code. Then you can run `npm run watch` to create your script with laravel mix.

Blade file loads Javascript files

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/sortable.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('is/myscript.js') }}"></script>
```

myscript.js is generated by `npm run watch`

```
import Sortable from "sortablejs";

var documentlists = $('#documentlist');
var sortable = Sortable.create(documentlists);
```

Maybe it even works when leaving out the first script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Ok First In `app.js` put

```
import Sortable from "sortablejs";
```

and make sure that it is imported => if you use vs code press ctrl + click on sortablejs if not just try
npm run watch then in your main blade import app.js

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

then do whatever you want